# A phrase containing all "special" characters

Tags: single-word-requests

A [pangram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram) is the phrase that contains all letters of given alphabet.

Is there any name for a phrase containing all "special" letters of given alphabet?

By "special" characters I understand all letters that differ that alphabet from standard alphabet from which it's derived (referred also as [diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic), though I'm not sure if it's usage isn't limited to Latin-derived alphabets and if, for example, ß is also a diacritic).

My question is inspired by [that question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6264/which-german-word-contains-the-most-a-o-u-and-ss-in-any-variation) on German.SE.

Comment: There's an underlying question: what _are_ the characters in say English. Some fonts include digraphs such as that for fi (here just two letters, of course) (oops) and near-obsolete letters such as Æ. It becomes fairly meaningless.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth you are rights, I've clarified the question to use the same terminology as the definition of pangram.

Comment: Ahem @EdwinAshworth As a Dane I strongly object to you calling one of our letters near-obsolete. http://wordfeuder.dk/ord-med-ae/

Comment: Ahem @mplungjan I was referring to the English Æ, not your letter, as I thought I'd made clear.

Comment: No, a sharp *s* / eszett is *NOT* a diacritic. Gosh.

Comment: I realize that I'm late, but the Hungarian alphabet has such a phrase: Árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép. Meaning 'A flood resistant mirror drill,' it was invented specifically for this purpose. Source: http://clagnut.com/blog/2380/#Hungarian

Answer (score 1):

Well, as a Czech native speaker, I can tell you it is impossible to create a sentence using **only** special characters. You can barely create a single word using them. There simply is no such thing, and therefore no such term.

The alphabet of any given language implicitly includes all those special characters, so pangram for the given language will include all the regular characters together with the special ones.